# mule-standalone-3.3.1 won't start on Windows 7

Tags: mule

I got following issue when starting mule server in windows 7.

I have set `JAVA_HOME` and `MULE_HOME` properly.

```
MULE_HOME is set to C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1 Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
--> Wrapper Started as Console Launching a JVM... Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
    "java" -Dmule.home="C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1"
-Dmule.base="C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3. :MaxPermSize=128m "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1\lib\endorsed"
-Xmx512m -Djava.library.path="%LD_LIBRARY_P
3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot" -classpath "%MULE_LIB%;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1/conf;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standal /commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot/log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-stan .3.1.jar;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot/mule-module-logging-3.3.1.jar;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-sta t-3.3.1.jar;C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1/lib/boot/wrapper-3.2.3.jar"
-Dwrapper.key="IqO3S6Ox0DeEiEkH" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dw port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=3224 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3"
-Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.mule.module.rebo Critical error: wait for JVM process failed Press any key to continue . . .
```

Environment

OS - Windows 7 64 bit

JAVA - 1.7.0_10 64 bit

Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Kasun.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like mule can't find the java executable. An easy way to address this is to edit the **${mule.home}/conf/wrapper.conf** file and specify the whole path for the property **wrapper.java.command**, i.e:

```
wrapper.java.command=c:/java7/jre/bin/java
```

On a side note you shouldn't set the **MULE_HOME** env var anymore since mule will take care of setting it itself upon statup.

Comment: Yes it works, But now I got another issue. This is the error. WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of the
          following files:
            wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll
            wrapper.dll
          could be located on the following java.library.path:
            C:\BAM\Linux\mule-standalone-3.3.1\bin\%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%
            C:\BAM\Linux\fresh\mule-standalone-3.3.1\mule-standalone-3.3.1\lib\boot
          Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path
          configuration property.
       System signals will not be handled correctly

Comment: It looks like a warning more than an error? Does mule start afterwards? Also is this mule ce? Because the community edition does not contain the wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll AFAIR

Comment: Yes it is mule CE. Because of this error my webapp doesn't deploy.

Comment: What do you mean by webapp? Do you mean mule app (i.e. the zip file generated by studio/maven) or are you running mule embedded in a webapp?

Answer (score 3):

Is your %JAVA_HOME%\bin; set as `Path` variable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. But in my case i had the MULE_HOME variable set to a wrong path. Once i deleted that variable, the error was resolved and the server started.