# Mule - Server start from command line in windows 7

Tags: mule

I am relatively very new to Mule development. I started development using Mule Studio and it was going good. 
Now that I have to install Mule environment on staging server and there I can't take Mule studio with me. Hence I will have to download Mule runtime environment and then will start server from there.

My questions are as following:
 
 
1. From where should I download the Mule runtime (.zip) file from? I could see for v2.x but not for v3.x!
 
 
2. Once I have that it would be fairly simple to pass arguments to Mule command file, I suppose. If it is not like that then please let me know how to do that.

I have tried to see on Internet but couldn't find any relevant material. Anyone sharing this would be appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: what was the solution that you found for this problem? My mule-app running in Anypoint, but does not in Runtime. I am using Runtime CE 3.7

Answer (score 4):

I wonder where you have looked for the Standalone. it's the same download page as the Studio.

1. You can download Mule Standalone (CE) from here: http://www.mulesoft.org/download-mule-esb-community-edition
2. To run it on Win7, you need admin privileges, so start the command line by right-clicking cmd, and `run as Administrator`. If you want to run it as a service (`mule start/stop`) in Windows, you need to install the service first with `mule install` command.

You may also encounter [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156300/mule-standalone-3-3-1-wont-start-on-windows-7).

Answer (score 1):

you can download Mule runtime server here :- http://www.mulesoft.org/download-mule-esb-community-edition   Once downloaded , Unzip it 
and the open the folder , go to the **bin** folder ... there you can see **Mule.bat** file...
now, 
you can open a command promt in that folder by  (pressing Shif button and right click, then select Open Command window here )..
Once you opened command window ... just type **Mule** or **Mule.bat** ......
Your Mule runtime server will start ...
Alternately if you type **mule install** ... Mule server will be installed in your machine and from next time will find the server already started on System Start